# WPF - Performance of GUI with lots of elements

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window with some list views that have very complicated ItemTemplates. The performance is horrid, it takes more than 200ms to populate the ListView, meaning scrolling and filtering on it are not user friendly at all.

I started trying to optimize performance by trial-and-error (since I cannot profile PresentationFramework effectively) and found some very odd things. For example, I got a noticable performance boost by moving the context menu from a  tag inside the DataTemplate to a static resource of the window, which I then reference as TextArea ContextMenu={StaticResource ...} (oddly enough, however, this does NOT increase performance if the DataTemplate itself is a StaticResource...)

Perhaps anybody here knows more about writing performance-effective code in WPF and can save me some time debugging? For reference, here's what my ItemTemplate looks like right now:

```
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Image Source="/HaMusic;component/Images/next_target.png" Height="{Binding Path=FontSize, ElementName=txtBlock}" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                        <Image.Visibility>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityToVisibilityConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="DataContext.ServerDataSource.NextItemOverride.UID" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                                <Binding Path="UID" />
                                <Binding Path="DataContext.ServerDataSource.NextItemOverrideAction" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Image.Visibility>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Item}" Width="Auto">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Value="True">
                                        <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityMultiConverter}">
                                                <Binding Path="DataContext.ServerDataSource.CurrentItem.UID" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                                                <Binding Path="UID" />
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                        <Setter Property="Background">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                                                    <GradientStop Offset="-2" Color="#4095FF" />
                                                    <GradientStop Offset="-1" Color="White" />
                                                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#4095FF" />
                                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="White" />
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                                                                    From="-2" To="0" Duration="0:0:4" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                                                                    From="-1" To="1" Duration="0:0:4" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                                                                    From="0" To="2" Duration="0:0:4" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Offset)"
                                                                    From="1" To="3" Duration="0:0:4" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Play" Click="MenuItem_PlayItem" />
                                <MenuItem Header="Play and Return" Click="MenuItem_PlayItemAndReturn" FontWeight="ExtraBold" />
                                <MenuItem Header="Play Next" Click="MenuItem_PlayItemNext" />
                                <MenuItem Header="Play Next and Return" Click="MenuItem_PlayItemNextAndReturn" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

New code with improvements (see comments for details):

```
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Image Source="/HaMusic;component/Images/next_target.png" Height="{Binding Path=FontSize, ElementName=txtBlock}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Visibility="Collapsed"
                           hmwpf:NextItemImageBehavior.NextItemImage="{Binding DataContext.ServerDataSource.NextItemOverride, ElementName=parent}"
                           Tag="{Binding DataContext.ServerDataSource, ElementName=parent}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto"
                               Text="{Binding Item}"
                               ContextMenu="{StaticResource contextMenu}"
                               hmwpf:AnimatedCurrentItemBehavior.AnimatedCurrentItem="{Binding DataContext.ServerDataSource.CurrentItem, ElementName=parent}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

(AnimatedCurrentItem and NextItemImage are attached properties implementing the exact same logic that the multibindings did, but in C# code instead of in XAML)

Even after all these changes, I am still about 100% slower than just rendering a plain TextBlock, for seemingly no reason (since the Image and Background special stuff are all invisible/not happening in my test environment). I think the bindings themselves are really tough on the framework, but when I add more bindings to random things to test it, it doesn't become even slightly slower...

Comment: how many items are binded to `ListView`? if there are more than 100. I would ask to you if your users needs them all, if not (wich is maybe the answer, because really I dont think a human can work with more than 100 records at a time), then maybe your solution is `pagination`.

Comment: You mean bound to the ItemsSource or actually visible? There are probably well over 100k in the ItemsSource, but I've noticed WPF only renders those that are visible (in the current scroll range). Which is about 50.

Comment: Alright, I managed to get another pretty big performance boost by replacing the complicated bindings/multibinding with attached properties that implement the same logic in actual code

Comment: Maybe turning that textbox style and those storyboards into static resources will help a little? I'd also make sure that all properties involved in bindings are providing their values quickly. As for the number of items, it looks like you're already using UI virtualization (`ListView` uses a `VirtualizingStackPanel` by default, afaik) so that should not be a problem.

Comment: Yea, there are no styles anymore since I replaced all DataTriggers with attached behaviors to get rid of the bindings. I found a good way to benchmark this by setting the Height on the TextBox to 1, then I get ~1000 TextBoxes in the ListView so it takes a while to render. My original code finished it in 4 seconds, the new code (I'll edit it in the original post) does it in 1.3s, and just a "TextArea" with nothing in it renders in 0.7s... So I'm in a good spot, but it could be better.